# How to share a Data object among a set of delegates?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, delegates

Following the MVC pattern stressed in various Objective-C programming guides, when I use Model with Controller, I should set the Controller as the `delegate` of the given Model. Now I have a huge Data object that's very expensive to create, and there're a few Controllers that need to work with this Data object. As long as the `delegate` property is set to the right Controller the Data object will work fine for THAT controller. Is there a way to share this model among these controllers?

I've brainstormed for a while, but haven't thought of any especially good solutions. A few things that I've come up

1. use notification center (but it seems expensive to set up such a relationship just for this specific case)
2. make each method of the Data object take a `delegate` argument: this is what I'm currently using now, but it is clunky and is reaching its limit

**Edit**

Thanks for people who have suggested to me using an NSArray. I think I forget to include this subtlty:

For my case say one of the delegates, `A`, wants to query the Data object by using one of its specific methods. The result would be correct if the `delegate` field of the Data object is set to `A`. But from what I understand using an array and calling the method on every delegate wouldn't give me the answer I want.

*In fact since my Data object couldn't know which delegate is calling it, it can't give back the correct result even if it knows about all the delegates it should be associated with*

Any thought on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is setting up another level of indirection - each Controller will be communicating with a 'middleware' object, which in turn communicates with the Data object. In this way, the common delegate-delegatee approach is preserved while the Data object only needs to be created once - at the expense of added 'middleman' object for each Controller.

In my example, the 'middleware' object will have a Controller set as its delegate property, and when that Controller wants to know information about the Data object, the 'middleware' object will then use its delegate property to query information from the Data object.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `NSArray` with delegates and then just call the method on every delegate in your array. (Watch out for retain cycles).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use notifications you can try using a multicast delegate approach. In this you would keep an `NSMutableArray` of delegates instead of a single one. So instead of setting the delegate you would add and remove delegates from your delegate array. When calling a delegate you would then call that delegate method on each delegate in the array, checking each one if it response to that particular callback. 
You can also control the order the delegates are called in if you so wish since you create and manage the delegate array yourself.